# Change Interface Language of the Editor LaTeXiT (Mac OS)

Tags: editors

I downloaded LaTeX for Mac OS, the interface language of the editor [LaTeXiT](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en) is French. I want to change it to English.

Here's a screenshot of the menu bar:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by bar menu and in what? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: LaTeX is a typesetting system, and doesn't really have a language (unless you count the commands, which are already in English).  LaTeX definitely doesn't have a menu bar.  My guess is that your TeX source code viewer is in French, but that's a separate program.  Changing it depends on which program you have.  Some common ones are TeXworks and TeXshop.  Do you have one of those?

Comment: @Teepeemm The question seems to be about LaTeXiT.

Comment: Then this question seems to be a bit unclear because ajocm says that latex is downloaded and also talking about Latex-it. Initially, I thought it was like "I downloaded latex and it is in French".

Comment: Go to the `Language & Region` Tab of `System Preferences` and move `English` above `French` in the `Preferred languages` list.

Comment: @egreg you are correct :)

Comment: If it's about LaTeXiT, then it's a Mac OS X question, off topic for this site. It has nothing to do with TeX and friends, but only with the OS interface.

Comment: I changed the title and tweaked the question - I hope that is ok for you.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the `Language & Region` Tab of `System Preferences` and move `English` above `French` in the `Preferred languages` list.

Comment: Where is the `Language & Region` ?

Comment: This was a useful answer for me even though it was not about La(Tex) per se.

Comment: For those who don't have English in your Preferred language list like me, just add English to the list will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot try it myself since I am working on a Windows system.

### Interface Language in LaTeXiT

LaTeXiT seems to be a kind of **equation editor** for **Mac OS** (from the [website](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit) "Should LaTeXiT be categorized, it would be an equation editor.").

According to the [website](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-features.php?lang=en) there should be translations available:

[image]

I tried to translate your screenshot of the menu - I assumed that there would be something like an option menu but there wasn't.

> I assume that you can change the interface language in the **Édition**
>   menu item. I recommend that you contact the author of LaTeXit, see [here](https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-contact.php?lang=en).

### Alternative LaTeX Editor (e. g. Texmaker)

I do not know what you try ta achieve but I assume that a normal LaTeX editor like **[Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)** would be more suitable. I made a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4uIAOPq1UE) (for Windows) how to install LaTeX and about the first steps - maybe it helps you.

[image]